# Script being executed before all each() has completed

Tags: jquery, each

After some debugging, it seems that code after the each statement is being executed before the each has completed.

I also noticed that the each function was cycling twice.

This is what happens:

1. Click on the #ProductsSubmit element
2. Alert popups up with the message: 'Event Triggered'  -- (The #ProductSubmit click event is only being triggered once. The alert box only pops up once.)
3. By using Firefox firebug, I can see that the get function is being called 4 times. There are only 2 .AddProduct elements. When looking at the URL that contains the grabbed element ids, I can see the .each() function is cycling through twice, but remember that the #ProductSubmit click event is only being triggered once.
4. The first alert(ErrorFound) is popping up with the value of 0. I verified that the get callback is triggering the if(VerifyData['Valid']!='Yes') statement. So the if statement is true 100% of the time (for debugging)
5. Settimeout is triggered. Alert popup is showing alert(ErrorFound) as 1.

So it looks like the alert(ErrorFound) is being triggered before ErrorFound is set to 1 in the each statement. But when I put a delay on it, it seems to catch up and show what the value should be, which is 1.

```
var ErrorFound;

$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).delegate("#ProductsSubmit", 'click', function(){ 
alert('Event Triggered');
ErrorFound = 0;
$(".AddProduct").each(function(){ 
    var IDToConfirm = $(this).attr('id');
    var SKUToConfirm = $(this).val();
        $("#"+IDToConfirm).removeClass("InputError");
        $.get('http://www.example.com/script.php?s='+SKUToConfirm+'&ut='+IDToConfirm, function(data) { 
            var VerifyData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(VerifyData['Valid']!='Yes') { ErrorFound = 1; $("#"+VerifyData['ID']).addClass("InputError"); }
        });


});
// Alert box shows value as 0
alert(ErrorFound);
setTimeout("AlertError()", 5000);

return false;
});

});
function AlertError() {
// Alert box shows value as 1
alert(ErrorFound);
}
```

What is going on? I've tried so many work arounds, but haven't found any that works.

Comment: `$.get()` is asynchronous. Read up on Promises.

Comment: `.delegate()` is deprecated, use `.on()`

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: Why do all your variables start with caps? Usually, this is a common practice to name constructors. See your variables are all blue...

Comment: I never use the SetTimeout function. Just used it here for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that your .each loop is going to run continuously regardless of the status of your ajax calls. The ajax calls respond to callback functions, and are not procedural like the rest of the code is.

The issue of 4 calls being performed when there are only two iterations expected, that is a tricky one.. I'd say try using something other method of selection besides delegate to test the behavior in a different but similar scenario (you can use .click, .on('click'), .bind('click'), .live('click') <- deprecated).. just check it out to get a fuller picture.

Comment: I will update the code to use non-deprecated functions. Hopefully I can find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You're being redirected. Did you actually use that url?

Comment: @Brandon, It might not be a problem with anything you've shown us. It would be easier if you linked us to the page in question.